# UserID as property

Tags: asp.net, oop, userid

I have a problem with my class below:

Iam tring to hold UserID without Session and of course Querystring, I thought i can store it in my UserClass.

So when i try to get the ID for example: Default.aspx:

```
MyUserClass  userclass=new MyUserClass();//global

//(at button click)
userclass.GetUser(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
int UserID=userclass.UserID;
```

when i reload the page UserID=0 that i get  ok. then i tried to use a static variable for that. example:

```
static MyUserClass  userclass=new MyUserClass(); //global
//(at button click)
    userclass.GetUser(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
    int UserID=userclass.UserID;
```

i get the ID when i also reloaded the page, but  when somebody else logins , my ID changes with the other ID

how can i do that with this way or i mean with properties?

The class is:

```
public class MyUserClass
{
    private  int _UserID;
    public  int UserID
    {
        get
        {
            return _UserID;
        }
    }


    public int  GetUser(string UserName, string Pass)
    {
        int UserID=0;
        try
        {

            DB.conn.Close();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("pUserkontrol", DB.conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@puserName", UserName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPass", Pass);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DB.conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Load(dr);
            DB.conn.Close();
            if (dt.Rows.Count < 1)
            {

            }

            else
            {
                foreach (DataRow datarow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    _UserID = Convert.ToInt32(datarow["UserID"]);
                    //UserID = _UserID;



                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {



        }



        return UserID;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web is stateless by nature and as such each new request is "overwriting" the UserId value as it stands there is nothing to tie back the request back to your class. You need to use some sort of storage mechanism. As you've discounted using session and querystring I would suggest rolling your own lightweight ASP.NET membership provider and implementing IIdentity and IPrincipal and creating an Authentication Ticket (Cookie) through the provider in order to persist your post-login details (userId). Take a look at Brady Gasters blog and the comments posted there for how to do this.

http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0

This post implements the membership in MVC 3 using Sessions however the comments and other links on the page show how to manipulate the code and use cookies auth. Implementing it in Web Forms (if youre using webforms) should also be fairly straightforward too.

Comment: thank you so much , i cannot vote yet so thank you, this is the answer for me

Comment: No problem, if you can't vote just accept this answer - that will put a little tick against it and give me some rep! ;o)